# How to combine multiple rows into one rows in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using PL/SQL, and I have a very simple query:

```
select
t.dispatch_date,
t.route,
t.employee_name
from 
dispatch t
where
t.dispatch_date=trunc(sysdate)
```

However, the result will give me some data like below, because there can be multiple people are assigned in same route: (But I want to combine the name together with ||)

[image]

Is there any function I can use to achieve my goal?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not one for hyperbole, but there is literally a billion posts on SO about converting multiple rows to one row across all SQL's.

Comment: Just use `LISTAGG`! This question is kind of the definition of LISTAGG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `listagg()`:

```
select t.dispatch_date, t.route,
       listagg(t.employee_name, '||') within group (order by t.employee_name) as employee_names
from dispatch t
where t.dispatch_date = trunc(sysdate);
```